# Passing MutableLiveData between functions

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I have a function 'A' in a ViewModel that retrieves data from firebase and I assign the value to a `MutableLiveData<Int>` (all of this is wrapped in `onSuccessListener`)and return it. This function is called from another function 'B' in the same ViewModel. But when I try to return `MutableLiveData<Int>` from 'A', it is returned as 0 (the default value). But if I assign value for the `MutableLiveData<Int>` outside the onSuccessListener, then the value is being returned.

Code:

```
val num = MutableLiveData<Int>().default(0)

private fun A():Int {
   FirebaseOperation
     .addOnSuccessListener{  //it:DocumentSnapshot!
         num.value = it.num
     }
   return num.value.toInt() // outside onsuccesslistener, default value 0 is being returned
}

private fun B() {
   val num2 = A()
}
```

**Update:**
After learning about the firebase callback hell, I've switched to kotlin coroutine for firebase (implementing `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1` as a dependancy)
*Updated Code:*

```
private suspend fun A():DocumentSnapshot? {
     return Firebase.firestore.collection("collection").documet("document").get().await()
    }

private suspend fun B(): Int{
    val data = A()
    val user = data.toObject<User>()
    val num = user.num
    return num
}
```

But the main thread freezes and the app crashes with `Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send key event because the focused window has not finished processing all of the input events that were previously delivered to it.  Outbound queue length: 0.  Wait queue length: 9.)`

Answer (score 2):

If you use [kotlinx.coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines), you can use [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/suspend-coroutine.html).

```kotlin
private suspend fun A(): Int = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    FirebaseOperation.addOnSuccessListener{  // it: DocumentSnapshot!
        cont.resume(it.num)
    }
}

private suspend fun B() {
   val num2 = A()
}
```

Comment: So I switched to coroutines and since I use Firestore, I am using the org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1 dependency and I use `Firebase.firestore.collection("collection").documet("document").get().await()` but the main thread just freezes and crashes

Comment: @AnirudhGanesh is there any crash logs reported on logcat or device?

Comment: @AnirudhGanesh might happen if UI thread (Dispatchers.Main) is used for long running tasks, try the coroutine calling the B() override the context's dispatcher to Default or IO, like: `scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { /* B() */ }`

Answer (score 1):

The retrieval of data from firebase happens asynchronously or in other words the `addOnSuccessListener` callback is only invoked when the data is retrieved from the firebase. So the livedata is only updated when the callback is invoked.
when you call `A()` from `B()`, it returns 0 because it does not wait for the livedata to be updated (callback to be invoked) and just returns the default value.

When you simply update the livedata value outside the `addOnSuccessListener`, it is updated synchronously and hence you get the updated result

Comment: So is there a way to wait until data is fetched? If I remove onsuccesslistener then it would crash saying Task not yet complete.

Comment: @Anirudh Ganesh, do you use coroutines?

Comment: @AnirudhGanesh instead of returning a `Int` you should return the livedata itself and observe it for by calling `observe()` and whenever the value of livedata will be updated you will get the callback on your Observer.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of `LiveData` is to be updated after asynchronous work and to be observed. In function `A()` I see that you only add `SuccessListener` but no operation is executed, so `SuccessListener` is not invoked. In function `B()` you just retrieve a reference to `MutableLiveData` but don't observe it, so it always contains default value. Usually `LiveData` objects are observed in `Activity` or `Fragment`:

```
num.observe(lifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
    // here you retrieve changes of your "num" variable as parameter "it"
})
```

where `lifecycleOwner` - usually activity or fragment.

Comment: I do perform firebase operations and a data snapshot is returned, which is assigned to the num

Answer (score 1):

A way to get the value in function B without using coroutines and without observing the livedata by a lifecycle (which btw you can't do as you don't have a lifecycle owner in viewmodel and you should refrain from passing any to it), is to use a `MediatorLiveData`.

The main purpose of mediator live data is that depends on other livedata for it's value and it can observe other livedata without a lifecycle.

So you can create a `MediatorLiveData` inside the function B, then return the livedata from function A and then observe it using the `MediatorLiveData` in function B. That way, when the value will get updated in A, you will be notified in B.

You can read more about MediatorLiveData here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData

Answer (score 1):

You could have flow or you can directly feed your VM.

```
class YourViewModel:ViewModel(){

val num = MutableLiveData<Int>().default(0)

   private suspend fun A():DocumentSnapshot? {
     return Firebase.firestore.collection("collection").documet("document").get().await()
   }

   fun onSomeButtonClick(){
       viewModelScope.launch(Main){
          val num =  A()?.toObject<User>().num ?: return
          num.value = num
       }
   } 

}
```

or `flow` with `asLiveData` extension.

```
val num:LiveData<Int> = flow{
   val num =  A()?.toObject<User>()?.num ?: 0
   emit(num)
}.asLiveData()
```

In your `UI`, you can observe and get `id`.

Answer (score 1):

I somehow managed to merge both the functions and I've nested all the DB callbacks now. I don't think that's good for code readability though. I'll be trying out other alternatives meanwhile.