# Hold loop execution till a callback has completed

Tags: android, loops, kotlin, concurrency, async-await

I am looking for a good approach to make a while loop wait its iteration till a callback has been fired, please look at the sample pseudo code below, in my android project I am using Kotlin:

```
var count = 0 
var found = false

while(count < 3 && found) {
    callback A = {
        succcess() {
            count++
            found = true
        }

        failed() {
            count++
        }
    }

    SampleApi.start(A)
}
```

In above sample code, I want to make the while loop execution stop and hold and only increment the iteration once a callback method is triggered.

Comment: How about Coroutines?

Comment: Can you give some example how it can be achieved? @AnimeshSahu, i tried using  runBlocking but its not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing MutableLiveData between functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62254528/passing-mutablelivedata-between-functions)

Comment: @AnimeshSahu thanks for sharing the link, but this solution is not working on my situation

Comment: I don't want to write complete answer, but you can do it like this: https://pl.kotl.in/X09iwBsPc

Comment: shouldn't your while loop have `!found` instead of `found` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just response to your pseudo code above, below could be a solution for updating data only after getting response from API. Instead of while loop, just call below method by passing ZERO as starting parameter.

```
    fun recursiveMethodCall(count: Int){
    callback A = {
        succcess() {
            if (count < 2){
                found = true
                loopMethodCall(count+1)
            }
        }

        failed() {
            if (count < 2){
                loopMethodCall(count+1)
            }
        }
    }

    SampleApi.start(A)
}
```