# How do I return a result from a callable cloud function?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, google-cloud-functions

I want to set up a test function to return values from my backend, but I can't figure out how to grab and parse the result in my app. I found an answer on here that says to use the code I've marked below, but I'm getting a bunch of errors. How do I return ***N*** number of values from a cloud function?

**Client code:**

```
//Database Kotlin file
fun test(data: Map<*,*>): Map<*,*> {
        val functions = Firebase.functions
        return functions.getHttpsCallable("test")
                .call(data)
                .continueWith { task ->
                    // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                    // has failed then result will throw an Exception which will be
                    // propagated down.
                    val result = task.result
                    //Other answer showed this JSON solution
                    val json = Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable)
                    val jsonString = org.json.JSONObject(result?.data as Map<*, *>).toString()
                    json.parse(Person.serializer(), jsonString)
                }
    }

//On the Activity
testbutton.setOnClickListener() {
            var data = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
            data["input1"] = "input1"
            data["input2"] = "input2"

            db.test(data)
            //Interpret results here
        }
```

**Backend:**

```
exports.test = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  return {returnVal: 777, returnMsg: 'test return message'}
});
```

**Errors:**

1. Right now the error is saying that there is a `Type Mismatch Required: Map<*,*> Found: Task<???,???>`. However, I think this is probably because I'm way off in setting up `test()`.

Comment: "I'm getting a bunch of errors" Please edit your question to show the exact error message and stack trace.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes, sorry I left that because I was trying a bunch of different things to get it to work, which created a bunch of different errors lol.

Comment: You either have to accept an argument of a lambda `(Map<>) -> Unit` that you can call after parsing the data, or use coroutines if you really want to return from a non-blocking function.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu can you add as an answer?

Comment: I'm surprised that the way to do this is so difficult to find online. I've been searching for over an hour on how to simply return a value(s) from a callable but I can't find anything.

Comment: Callables do not yield JSON via the Android SDK.  They yield a Java object whose form matches that of the object returned by the function.  Remove everything that has to do with JSON and just inspect the object you get from the task.  Also, the call to call() is asynchronous and returns a Task.  You can't simply cast that Task to a Map and expect that to work.  You have to handle the result inside the continuation callback.  If you want the Task result to be easier to use in kotlin, you should look into using coroutines and covert that Task to something that can be used in a coroutine.

Comment: First way is straight forward, you can simply pass a callback that could be called sometime in future, I don't see any point to add an answer, if you want to get the result from the function I already have written a simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62259007/11377112 using coroutines.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson that worked. You're amazing.

Comment: @DougStevenson would you mind creating an answer with the solution provided? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Callables do not yield JSON via the Android SDK. They yield a Java object whose form matches that of the object returned by the function. Remove everything that has to do with JSON and just inspect the object you get from the task. Also, the call to call() is asynchronous and returns a Task. You can't simply cast that Task to a Map and expect that to work. You have to handle the result inside the continuation callback. If you want the Task result to be easier to use in kotlin, you should look into using coroutines and covert that Task to something that can be used in a coroutine.